# MS Bot framework emulator chang user id

Tags: c#, emulation, botframework

Is there a way to change the default user id (which is 'default-user')  in bot emulator?

Or maybe it supports something about multi conversations in the same time?

I want to emulate two different users at the same time (because I have multiple user types in my project.

When I try to create new conversation like this

```
....
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(context.Activity.ServiceUrl));
var userAccount = new ChannelAccount("//here we need to provide user id which is always default-user", "Provider");
var botAccount = context.Activity.Recipient;

var conversation = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);
var message = context.MakeMessage();
message.Recipient = userAccount;
message.From = botAccount;
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(false, conversation.Id);
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity) message);
```

My emulator opens new conversation in the same chat-window

Answer (score 2):

`Bot Framework Channel Emulator` had the functions you need in the previous versions. In the latest one AFAIK changing user id and group conversation simulation are not available out of the box. However the good thing is that what this tool is doing - it is just sending http requests to your `WebApi` endpoint. It means that you can catch those requests using `Fiddler` or any other similar tool and then edit and reissue the request. It is a workaround, but for testing pusposes I think it is okay to use such an approach.

Below is the Fiddler screen and screen of debug session to show it is working:

[image: Fiddler reissued request]

[image: Activity variable value during debug]

If you want to go further and automate it - there is a [REST Api documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-overview) on botframework site, so you can build your own client.

Comment: Yeye i know that i cant do this... but... it is so strange that MS dont allow it in emulator, you know. And i need to receive responses for two different users also , not only requests. Is there a way to get older version?

Comment: Emulator is an open source project with MIT license, so you can't really blame them. But I totally agree it would be great to have such a functionality

Comment: Regarding old version I am not sure it would be working as there were some breaking change moving to 3.5 and 3.8 versions. However you may check for older versions here on their github repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator

Comment: Why did they remove functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I work on the Bot Framework Emulator. We've recently added the ability to override generated user ids to be used in conversations without the need of a tool like Fiddler. You can utilize this feature in our [latest release](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/latest). I hope you find this useful for your scenario.

Comment: Is there any documentation available on adding a user. I can see there is `User Settings - Use your own id to communicate with bot` but not sure how to add one and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way of having multiple conversations with different users, but you cant change the id/name of the user that is currently sending messages.

You can do this by editing the config file that the emulator uses to store its settings.

On linux I found this settings file here:
`~/.config/botframework-emulator/botframework-emulator/server.json`

You'll find a section "users" in that json file.

Change that section to:

```
"users": {
    "currentUserId": "default-user2",
    "usersById": {
      "default-user": {
        "id": "default-user",
        "name": "User"
      },
      "default-user2": {
        "id": "default-user2",
        "name": "User2"
      }
    }
```

You'll need to restart the emulator and then your conversation should be with User2 now instead of User.

When you want to change it back you just need to change:

```
"currentUserId": "default-user2",
```

back to

```
"currentUserId": "default-user",
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows follow these steps:

1. go to directory
   %APPDATA%\botframework-emulator\botframework-emulator
2. locate server.json file
3. In the sections of users replace default-user
   with id you need (in my case romel)
   "users": {
   "currentUserId": "default-user",
   "usersById": {
     "default-user": {
       "id": "romel",
       "name": "User"
     }
   }
   }
4. restart bot emulator